# Use of undeclared identifier 'yylval'

Tags: compiler-construction, bison, flex-lexer, yacc, lex

I tried to run this program in lex and yacc. I work on a Macbook Pro.

I don't understand why is not recognised the yylval in lex file;
does someone know what should I do here?
I perhaps need to add some includes, or something else? I did find something on the internet like this:

lex file:

```
%% 

August { yylval = 8; return AUGUST; }
September { yylval = 9; return SEPTEMBER; }
October { yylval = 10; return OCTOBER; }
November { yylval = 11; return NOVEMBER; } 
December  { yylval = 12; return DECEMBER; }
20[0-9][0-9]        { yylval = atoi(yytext); return YEAR; }
.        return yytext[0];
%%
```

yacc file:

```
%{
  
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "lex.yy.c"


int yylex(void);
int yyerror();

%}


%token AUGUST SEPTEMBER OCTOBER NOVEMBER DECEMBER 
%token YEAR

%%

s: month '#' YEAR

{
    printf("%d  %d\n",$1,$3);
    printf("DATE IS OK\n");
}

month  :  AUGUST {$$ = $1;}
      |  SEPTEMBER {$$ = $1;}
      |  OCTOBER {$$ = $1;}
      |  NOVEMBER {$$ = $1;}
      |  DECEMBER{$$ = $1;}
%%



int main(){
    return yyparse();
}

int yyerror(){
    printf("Error in date\n");
    return 0;
}
```

when i run this

```
lex file.l 
yacc file.y
gcc -o file y.tab.c -ll
```

this the error i get!:

```
In file included from test.y:8:
test.l:3:3: error: use of undeclared identifier 'yylval'
{ yylval = 8; return AUGUST; }
  ^
test.l:4:3: error: use of undeclared identifier 'yylval'
{ yylval = 9; return SEPTEMBER; }
  ^
test.l:5:3: error: use of undeclared identifier 'yylval'
{ yylval = 10; return OCTOBER; }
  ^
test.l:6:3: error: use of undeclared identifier 'yylval'
{ yylval = 11; return NOVEMBER; } 
  ^
test.l:7:3: error: use of undeclared identifier 'yylval'
{ yylval = 12; return DECEMBER; }
  ^
test.l:8:3: error: use of undeclared identifier 'yylval'
{ yylval = atoi(yytext); return YEAR; }
  ^
6 errors generated.
```

Comment: You need to find a better guide, I think. Don't put this in your yacc file: `#include "lex.yy.c"`. That's just wrong, and if you see it in a supposed example, you should probably find a different source.

Comment: You need to generate a yacc header file (`-d` option) and `#include` it (the *header* file, `y.tab.h`) in your lex file. You'll need some other includes in your lex file, as well, since you use `atoi`. And you need to add the generated scanner (`lex.yy.c`) to your compile command.

Comment: It's worth reading the first few sections of the [bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html) and [flex](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/) manuals. (Those manuals are for the most recent versions. If you use a Mac, you might have ancient versions of bison and flex, which you should upgrade.)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the method of using `#include "lex.yy.c"` in your yacc/bison file then you should put the include line at the **bottom** of the yacc/bison file. Then  the declarations will have been made by yacc/bison prior to being referenced in by the lex/flex generated code.

Yes; there are other ways of solving this as explained in the comments, but there are also many texts and examples that use this method which students are learning from.

You will find my method will solve the issue, although I also agree with the other methods listed in the comments.